# Pandas DataFrame, divide a column having multiple values into multiple columns and remove null values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe, whose one particular column has temperature values like shown below

```
'35-40',
 '35-40',
 '40-45',
 '40-45',
 '45-50',
 '40-45',
 '40-45',
 nan,
 '40-45',
 nan,
 '40-45',
 '40-45',
 '35-40',
```

I am trying to create a new column separating minimum and maximum temperatures.
In the rows filled with 'nan', I want the values after ',' to also be 'nan'. how should I do this? I have tried the code below but it didn't work.

```
train["Maximum Temperature"] = train["Cellar Temperature"].apply(lambda x: np.nan if train["Cellar Temperature"][0]==np.nan else (str(x).split("-")[1]))
```

Whenever I run the above code I get the following error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. What do you mean by _I want the values after ‘,’ to also be ‘nan’_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
train[["Minimum Temperature", "Maximum Temperature"]]=train["Cellar Temperature"].str.split("-", expand=True, n=1)
```

`str.split()` will split string by provided delimiter - `-` in this case. Then `expand` will explode splitted array, so every element will go into separate column. Then `n=1` will limit max splits to 1 (otherwise you would get an error, in case if you would have more than 1 hyphen in any cell).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `extract` to get both:

```
df['temp'].str.extract('(?P<minimum>\d+)-(?P<maximum>\d+)')
```

Output:

```
   minimum maximum
0       35      40
1       35      40
2       40      45
3       40      45
4       45      50
5       40      45
6       40      45
7      NaN     NaN
8       40      45
9      NaN     NaN
10      40      45
11      40      45
12      35      40
```

Answer (score 0):

To directly correct your code, try

```
train["Maximum Temperature"] = train["Cellar Temperature"].apply(lambda x: np.nan if pd.isnull(x) else x.split("-")[1])
```